Let $f(x) = a_1 \sin(x) + a_2 \sin(2x) +\dots +a_n \sin(nx)$, if $|f(x)| \leq |\sin(x)|$ show that $|\sum_{i=1}^{n} ia_i| \leq 1$
Let $$f(x) = a_1 \sin(x) + a_2 \sin(2x) +\dots + a_n\sin(nx)$$, if $$|f(x)| \leq |\sin(x)|$$ show that $$|\sum_{i=1}^{n} ia_i| \leq 1$$  where $a_i$ are real numbers
The contrapositive is $|{a_1+2a_2+ \dots  +na_n}| >1 \implies |f(x)|>|sin(x)|$
Base case $|a_1| >1 \implies |a_1 sin(x)|> |sin(x)|$
Inductive hypothesis $|a_1|+2|a_2| + \dots+ n|a_n| >1 \implies a_1sin(x)+a_2sin(x)+ \dots+ a_nsin(x) >1$
It trivially follows that $|a_1|+2a_2+ \dots + (n+1)|a_{n+1}| >1$. It thus follows that $$|a_1|sin(x)+|2a_2||sin(2x)| + \dots + |(n+1)a_{n+1}| |sin(nx)| > |sin(x)|$$
Now I've seen this answer here, that simply asks us to divide acorss by $x$, which to be fair, is an elegant solution but I wanted to know if my idea could take use anywhere

Your inductive hypothesis is already incorrect because you replace $|\sum i a_i|$ with $\sum i |a_i|$. Besides, I don't think induction can work because the real argument is that the slope of $f$ at $0$ must be smaller than the slope of $\sin x$.

The question should specify $\forall x \in A, |f(x)|\le|\sin x|$ where $A$ is a neighbourhood of $x=0$.
